# get redirected url from XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript

I'd like to get the redirect url from a site via XMLHttpRequest

Here's the code below

```
let url = 'https://some-site.com/Z/12345/54321'
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(response) {
    
  var xhr2 = response.target;
  console.log(xhr.location)
  if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 302) { 
    var redirectURL = xhr.location; 
  }  
}

xhr.onerror = (response) => {
    debugger
}

xhr.open('GET', url, true);
xhr.send();
```

so the problem is, the website, as the code below

```
let url = 'https://some-site.com/Z/12345/54321'
```

is only redirecting to another website

I only want to get the redirect url

I don't know how the ***`'https://some-site.com/Z/12345/54321'`*** coded

so the TLDR is send request to ***`'https://some-site.com/Z/12345/54321'`***  => from ***`'https://some-site.com/Z/12345/54321'`*** redirected to `the url that I want to get`

Is there any way to get the url?

Comment: So when you make the AJAX call, the browser is redirecting to the site returned in the `302` response?

Comment: @BenRondeau its' 0

Answer (score 1):

You should use [XMLHttpRequestInstance.responseURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseURL):

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
xhr.open('GET', 'https://some-site.com/Z/12345/54321'); xhr.responseType = 'json'
xhr.onload = function(){ /* no need to use onreadystatechange in xhr2 */
  // this.response is JSON response
  // this.responseURL is what you want
}
xhr.onerror = function(e){
  // e is ErrorEvent Obj
}
xhr.send();
```